# Use Cases for Redis' "Score" and "Ranking" Features for Sets

Tags: redis

What are some use cases for Redis' "score" and "ranking" features for sets (outside of the typical "leaderboard" examples for games?  I'm trying to figure out how to make use of these dynamic new features as I anticipate moving from using a traditional relational database to Redis as a persistent data store.

Answer (score 5):

`ZSET`s are great for selections or ranges based on scores, but scores can be any numerical value, like a timestamp.

We store daily stock prices for all US stocks in redis. Here's an example for ebay...

```
ZADD key score member [score member ...] 
...
ZADD stocks:ebay 1 30.39 2 32.70 3 31.25 4 31.75 5 29.12 6 29.87 7 29.93
```

The `score` values in this case would normally be long timestamps, with that aside, if we want daily prices for the last 3 days, we simply convert two dates to timestamps and pull from redis using the timestamp range `1 3`...

```
zrangebyscore stocks:ebay 1 3

1) "30.39"
2) "32.70"
3) "31.25"
```

The query is *very* fast and works well for our needs.

Hope it helps!

Comment: A zset is not a binary tree. It is a combination of dictionary and skip list. The algorithmic complexity is also different.

Comment: Redis source code: https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/t_zset.c#L31

Comment: There may be a flaw in this approach: as this is a SET, when adding a repeated stock price it won't be stored! `ZADD stocks:ebay 8 30.39`

Answer (score 1):

zset is the only type of key who can be sorted

by example you can imagine puts all comments key id of a specific article in a zset,
users will vote up/down each comments and this will change the score value

after that when you need to draw comments you can get them ordered, better comments in first place (like here)

using ZREMRANGEBYSCORE you can imagine delete all pretty bad comments each days

but as each redis type, they still basic, give you a dedicated use case is hard there can be some :- )