# Get all keys based on time in Redis

Tags: python, redis

How do I get a list of keys based on time in Redis, or based on a chronological key which is within the dictionary, i.e.:

```
get foo
{"time":'Thu Aug 15 22:37:37 2013', "data":"etc"}
```

And I have the `"time"` key within every one of my Redis entries. How do I fetch a list sorted based on that time, or better, the time when the keys are created?

Comment: You cannot. You need to build a zset to index your time-serie data structure.

Comment: Use a sorted set: I gave a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18027498/791406), principals are the same:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is a keystore and isn't meant to be operated as you're trying.  The 'time' key is irrelevant to redis as this is just a JSON string stored in a Redis string(if I'm understanding correctly).  Basically, Redis doesn't care what's in the string, and if it did, it may as well be a full SQL DB.

If you absolutely have to use time, you could include that in the key name.  For instance, you want to get all keys in August:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> MSET foo_20130815223737 "{\"time\":'Thu Aug 15 22:37:37 2013', \"data\":\"etc\"}"  foo_20130816123015 "{\"time\":'Thu Aug 16 12:30:15 2013', \"data\":\"etc\"}"
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS foo_201308*
1) "foo_20130815223737"
2) "foo_20130816123015"
```

If you describe why you're trying to do this, I may have a better option.  For instance, a Pub/Sub using Redis as a message queue may fit your intentions better.

Comment: Poor advice. Don't use the KEYS command in the proposed way - it will not work when you have a significant number of keys because of the O(n) complexity.

Comment: @DidierSpezia Fair enough, but it was the only solution I could come up with for his specific requirements using Redis.

Comment: I am trying to list all of the keys within the database because I have pages (user created) within that database and I need to list them all in respect to their creation time.

Comment: Then, build a data structure to support this access path. A zset should help you.